# Model validation using DataAnnotations [DataType(DataType.Currency]

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I'm trying to validate model with custom error message:

```
[Display(Name = "Iznos Prihoda")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Molimo unesite iznos prihoda!")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency, ErrorMessage = "Molimo unesite ispravni format valute!")]
public decimal IznosPrihod { get; set; }
```

And I'm getting the default error message

> The field Iznos Prihoda must be a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
[Display(Name = "Iznos Prihoda")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Molimo unesite iznos prihoda!")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.?\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = ""Molimo unesite ispravni format valute!")]
```

Comment: Hi, it worked. Thx.

[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.?\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Molimo unesite ispravni format valute!")]

Comment: @Jogi6 Sorry, it  is for currency type since you put in data annotation. 2 means 2 numbers after dot. This is what the most currencies have. If you need it just for number it is quite different.

Comment: @Jogi6 you can try this @"^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$" and let me know

Comment: Hi, I do need it for Currency, but in format "1234,56" not "1234.56"